# How get rid of these warnings?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, swift3

After updating all my pods to Swift 3, I get some weird warnings, and I can't seem to get rid of them. They seems to belong either to removed or updated pods. The alamofire has been updated, and the warnings it gives is because the files is renamed in the new version (Stream.swift in screenshot). The EVReflection is completely removed, however it still shows these warnings. I've tried to clean project and clean build folder, no effect whatsoever. Any suggestions? I kinda hit a rock here.

[image]

Also this one:

[image]

In addition to this, I've updated all my pods and code til Swift 3, but xCode is still asking me to convert when started, how come?

Comment: Run pod install again.

Comment: I've done that several times, it doesn't sort anything. It seems like it has a reference to something outdated. I've also tried to deintegrate it and pod install, nothing seems to solve these warnings.

Comment: Have you cleaned the project and the build folder?

Comment: Yea, I did. Should I try to clear derivedData?

Answer (score 0):

Try committing your changes and see if that works:

`git add .`

`git commit -m "commit"`